# Updating a Table using a CTE

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, sql-update, common-table-expression

I asked a similar question regarding Oracle, but every DBMS is different.

I have a sample table at https://dbfiddle.uk/i2wN57xq . I would like to update the table using data from a CTE. Something like this:

```sql
with vars as (select 5 as n from dual)
update test set data=data*vars.n, more=more*vars.n;
```

This doesn’t work, of course. How can I use data from a CTE in an `UPDATE` statement?

Note:

- I know the sample is trivial, but I’m just looking for the correct technique.
- Most of my searches result in attempts to update the CTE itself. I don’t want to do that, just use the CTE for its data.

I’ve found a solution for PostgreSQL and SQL Server. For Oracle, I ended up with a subquery, which is fine, since I can get multiple results from the subquery. I would settle for something like that if it won’t work with a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CROSS` join the table to the `CTE` in the `UPDATE` statement for MySql:

```
WITH vars AS (SELECT 5 AS n)
UPDATE test t 
CROSS JOIN vars v
SET t.data = t.data * v.n, 
    t.more = t.more * v.n;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zoyWuzRc)

For MariaDB:

```
UPDATE test t 
CROSS JOIN (
  WITH vars AS (SELECT 5 AS n)
  SELECT * FROM vars 
) v
SET t.data = t.data * v.n, 
    t.more = t.more * v.n;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/79rAIpr_).

Or simpler (without the CTE):

```
UPDATE test t 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 5 AS n) v
SET t.data = t.data * v.n, 
    t.more = t.more * v.n;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5PqylC0G).

Comment: I tried it in the fiddle, but I get an error message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE test t 
CROSS JOIN vars v
SET t.data = t.data * v.n, 
    t.more = t.m...' at line 2`

Comment: I can see a problem. Your sample uses MySQL 8.0, and it does work. Mine uses MariaDB 10.6 and it doesn’t. I had imagined they would be compatible.

Comment: @Manngo You tagged both MySql and MariaDB. The CTE can be used as you want it in MySql but not with MariaDB. In MariaDB the syntax would be different and maybe the use of the CTE is pointless. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. I generally think of MariaDB as more with-it but clearly MySQL beats it in this case. It was a similar issue with Oracle.

Comment: Yes, MariaDB and MySQL both implemented the CTE feature after MariaDB forked in 2010, so their implementations are different. In MySQL, the statements that can follow a CTE are SELECT, UPDATE, or DELETE. In MariaDB, you can follow a CTE only with a SELECT. This is just what they chose to implement. MariaDB is effectively a totally different product from MySQL, because there are numerous incompatibilities, and more with every release.